Dart analyzer error for missing parameter type in function declaration
I've just noticed that it is perfectly possible to misspell if and not get any error.
i( confirm ){
  save();
}

Since this is interpreted as declaring the function i with a parameter named confirm of the type dynamic, this results in a warning about "The declaration 'i' isn't referenced.", which is easy to miss. Especially when just looking quickly at the code.
This kind of mistake would be prevented if declaring a function with parameters that don't have types resulted in an error.
Is there any option for the Dart analyzer that specifically targets parameters in function declarations?
I am aware of
analyzer:
  language:
    strict-casts: true
    strict-inference: true
    strict-raw-types: true

but they don't fit this use case, and enabling them on legacy projects results in thousands of "errors".
I specifically want to target only function declarations with parameters that don't have types.
